# docker-compose fails when bringing up vagrant box

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I have a task to create some Docker Containers within a Vagrant Box (centos/7) but I'm having issues with the "vagrant up" execution.

Within the vagrant instance I'm using docker-compose to spin up the services.

Here is the error I am getting when docker-compose is called:

```
> ==> default: [Provisioning] Bring up Docker Containers
> ==> default: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
> ==> default:
> ==> default: If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

If I check the vagrant instance I can see that docker is running and that my user is part of the docker group

```
c:\temp\vagrant\kpi-engine>vagrant ssh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps aux | grep docker
root       425  0.1  4.6 496652 23152 ?        Ssl  09:54   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd
root       428  0.0  1.0 265176  5360 ?        Ssl  09:54   0:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim do
cker-containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --runtime docker-runc
vagrant   1363  0.0  0.1 112652   972 pts/0    S+   09:55   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ grep vagrant /etc/group
vagrant:x:1000:vagrant
docker:x:992:vagrant
```

However, if I run a "vagrant provision" after "vagrant up" everything runs through successfully with Docker.

```
==> default: [Provisioning] Clone repositories
==> default: fatal: destination path 'kpi_data' already exists and is not an empty directory.
==> default: [Provisioning] Bring up Docker Containers
==> default: Creating network "vagrant_default" with the default driver
==> default: Creating volume "vagrant_mongo_db" with default driver
==> default: Creating volume "vagrant_maria_db" with default driver
==> default: Pulling mariadb (docker-registry.ptk02.ipaccess.com/mariadb:latest)...
==> default: latest: Pulling from mariadb
==> default: Digest: sha256:d17cfbf8e7e9b9ed79f2de17125a01f66f350ddf5bcdd8b62da20634cfa0b425
==> default: Status: Downloaded newer image for docker-registry.ptk02.ipaccess.com/mariadb:latest
==> default: Pulling mongo (docker-registry.ptk02.ipaccess.com/mongo:latest)...
==> default: latest: Pulling from mongo
==> default: Digest: sha256:4059a5c7c1f7d44a0ea3c1f8bda0e240f74f8cf16d6cc08e81d0fbc59b475553
==> default: Status: Downloaded newer image for docker-registry.ptk02.ipaccess.com/mongo:latest
==> default: Creating mongo
==> default: Creating mariadb
```

Docker is installed using the vagrant provisioner

```
config.vm.provision :docker
```

I ran "vagrant up" with --debug but it did not provide any more insight.

Any thoughts as to what could be the issue.